# Qt serial port, when i write, i can not read what i write

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port

I can see what i write in the write buffer, however, there is no signal for ready read, and even if i use the read fonction there is nothing in the read buffer.
Here is my code:

```
    void Widget::ouvrir_port_com()
{
    struct PortSettings myComSetting = {BAUD57600,DATA_8,PAR_NONE,STOP_1,FLOW_OFF,100};

    myCom = new Win_QextSerialPort(port_com,myComSetting,QextSerialBase::EventDriven);

    if(myCom ->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))// si il est ouvert
    {
        //QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Ouvert reussi"), tr("Ce port est ouvert") + port_com, QMessageBox::Ok);
    }else// si il est pas ouvert
    {
        QMessageBox::critical(this, tr("Echec de l'ouverture"), tr("Ce port de com ne peut pas être ouvrire ") + port_com + tr("\n Ce port de com n'est pas dipnible"), QMessageBox::Ok);
         return;
    }

    connect(myCom,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(readCom()));

    send_command();
}

void Widget::readCom()

{
    QByteArray temp = myCom->readAll();

    ui->textBrowser->insertPlainText(temp);
}

void Widget::send_command()
{
    QString x="OK ou pas?";
    myCom->write(x.toLatin1());
    myCom->flush();

    myCom->readyRead();
}
```

Please help me!!!!

Comment: Well, now you wrote it, it's sent to the other device. You won't get readyRead for what you just wrote, but for what the device on the other end of the serial connection writes.

Comment: Is your other device that you write, sending back what it receives ?

Comment: Have you considered switching the official QtSerialPort add-on?

Answer (score 0):

you can read souce,posix_qextserialport.cpp line 147:"POSIX doesn't have event driven mechanism implemented yet"
so you can new a timer and poll at 100ms.